# Complex django query including one-to-one models

Tags: python, django

I have an user object which has a one-to-relationship with a profile object.

```
class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    email = models.EmailField(unique=True, max_length=255)
    mobile = PhoneNumberField(null=True)
    username = models.CharField(null=False, unique=True, max_length=255)
    is_online = models.BooleanField(default=False)


class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User,related_name='profile',on_delete=models.CASCADE, )
    badge = models.ImageField(upload_to='media/badges/', null=True)
    reputation = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True, blank=True)
```

Now I'm trying to fetch all users who're online and order them by reputation(which is in the profile object) and exclude the ones that have a reputation less than 200.

This is my query which doesn't work,

```
User.objects.filter(is_online=True).order_by('reputation').exclude('reputation' < 200)
```

Can someone help with the correct format of this query?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well if you write `.exclude('reputation' < 200)`, then Python will first evaluate `'reputation' < 200` which will - in Python 3.x - fail to compare, and in Python-2.x return `False`, then you pass that boolean to a `exclude`.

But note that you never filter on the reputation at all. It is only a boolean (at best case), you pass to the filter.

You perform comparisons in Django with the parameter name: you use the `__lt` suffix to denote "*less than*".

Another thing is that you query on the `User`, but the reputation is stored in `UserProfile`, you thus need to follow the reverse foreign key (this reverse relation is for filter `profile`, and you access it again by using two consecutive underscores).

So we can solve the `exclude` part with:

```
(User.objects.filter(is_online=True)
                        .order_by('profile__reputation')
                        .exclude(profile__reputation__lt=200))
```

Note that if you exclude vlaues below 200, this is basically the same as filtering for values equal to and larger than 200, so we can move this to the `filter` section:

```
(User.objects.filter(is_online=True, profile__reputation__gte=200)
                        .order_by('profile__reputation'))
```

Answer (score 4):

The query can be improved like the following:

```
queryset = User.objects.filter(is_online=True,profile__reputation__gte=200)
           .order_by('profile__reputation')
```

Answer (score 3):

The query would probably be

```
qs = User.objects.filter(is_online=True, profile__reputation__gte=200)
qs = qs.order_by('profile__reputation')
```

---

But note that this will not be very performant for big tables as the sorting is done on the other table.

I suggest switching the base table to improve speed:

```
qs = UserProfile.objects.filter(user__is_online=True, reputation__gte=200)
qs = qs.order_by('reputation')
```